# Cannot connect to Internet via certain Wifi networks

Tags: wi-fi, lg-g3

my LG G3 recently started acting up in that it will not be able to access the Internet via my home WiFi. I can connect to the Internet on other WiFi networks so I don't think it's necessarily an issue with the phone. However, I can connect other devices to my home WiFi and access the internet without any problems whatsoever which implies nothing is wrong with the network. My phone is connecting to the WiFi network, it just cannot get to the internet.

LG G3
Android 4.4.2

Comment: Try forgetting the network and reconnect to it afresh.

Comment: Been there, done that  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved, sorta. I used a static IP on my phone and am now able to get to the internet. I'm not sure what has changed on my device to force me down this path but it is what it is.